# Date matching not working on date and object?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a variable which holds a date inputted by the user and converts it to date format using this code:

```
correct_date = "2022-06-08"
correct_date = dt.datetime.strptime(correct_date,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

I also have some embedded SQL in the same script that returns dates in YYYY-MM-DD format; these are saved into a dataframe:

```
actual_dates = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql = f"""
    SELECT DATE(CONTACTDATETIME) AS CONTACT_DATE
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DATE(CONTACTDATETIME);
    """,
    con = connection)
```

If work carried out elsewhere was done correctly, there should only be one date in the results from the SQL, which should match the date that was entered into the correct_date variable.

What I want to do is check whether this is the case. I have the code below to do this, but the problem is it always returns FAIL even when the only value in actual_dates matches correct_date.

```
if actual_dates["contact_date"].any() != correct_date:
    print("FAIL")
else:
     print("SUCCESS")
```

Does anyone know where I may be going wrong please? I have the suspicion it's because Python doesn't recognise a date and an object as being the same thing even when they're in YYYY-MM-DD format. Is this correct and if so does anyone know how I can work around this to achieve the required result please?

Answer (score 0):

In above case, you are comparing 'String' with Date object. which will always return False.

Instead, converting the string to Date, and then comparing will give correct result.
Check below code.

```py
if datetime.datetime.strptime(actual_dates["contact_date"],'%Y-%m-%d').date() != correct_date:
    print("FAIL")
else:
     print("SUCCESS")
```

Comment: Hi Liju, I tried this but it gave me the following error: "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series"

Comment: Try iterating over the series items and compare one by one.